# java mappings bits to strings

Tags: java, bit

we have days of week represented as ints.

```
1 = sunday
2 = monday
4 = tuesday
8 = wednesday
16 = thursday
32 = friday
64 = saturday
```

When we get an int as 88 - this would mean 64 + 16 + 8, so we need to derive that the schedule is wednesday, thursday & saturday.

I did it as follows but I guess there is a better way...

```
public List<String> getDays(int input) {
    List days = new ArrayList();
    days.add( (sunday & input!=0) ? "SUN" : "");
    days.add( (monday & input!=0) ? "MON" : ""); 
    ...
    ...
    return days;
}
```

Comment: Do you want a bunch of blank entries in your list?  That's what you get right now.

Comment: You could create a map of bits (ints) to days (strings) and iterate through the entries of the map, adding the days which have their bit in the input.  Alternatively, you could create an enum containing these mappings for a more OO approach.

Comment: You might want to check if the codereview community on stack exchange is a good place to ask this question (as soon as your current code is doing what it is expected to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an array containing the days and a loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getDays(88)); // [WED, THU, SAT]
}

public static List<String> getDays(int input){
    List<String> days = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] daysArr = {"SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"};
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++){
        if ((input & 1 << i) != 0){
            days.add(daysArr[i]);
        }
    }
    return days;
}
```

Comment: Why not to use `1 << i` instead of `(int)Math.pow(2, i)`? You should avoid floating point arithmetics

Comment: @hege_hegedus That's a nice one ! Will edit my post. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

You could play with binary representation of your number: `88` is `1011000` in binary, so just check the bits set to "one" and print the corresponding day of the week

```
static void checkNumber(int x){
    BigInteger bigX=BigInteger.valueOf(x);
    if(bigX.testBit(0))
        System.out.println("sunday");
    if(bigX.testBit(1))
        System.out.println("monday");
    if(bigX.testBit(2))
        System.out.println("tuesday");
    if(bigX.testBit(3))
        System.out.println("wednesday");
    if(bigX.testBit(4))
        System.out.println("thursday");
    if(bigX.testBit(5))
        System.out.println("friday");
    if(bigX.testBit(6))
        System.out.println("saturday");
}
```